# Why I can't import the AngularFire in this simple TypeScript class into an Angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am very new in **Angular** and **FireBase** and I have this problem following a course on Udemy.

The instructor implements this class using **AngularFire** project to perform an example query on the Firebase DB:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';


  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {

      const courses$: FirebaseListObservable<any> = af.database.list('courses');         // It is an Observable ($)

      courses$.subscribe(
          val => console.log(val)
      );
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can't import the **AngularFire** type used as input parameter of my constructor and I can't understand why (putting the mouse coursor on this type I am not obtaining the choise to import this type into the import list).

What could be the problem? I should have installed **AngualarFire dependency), this is the content of my **package.json** dependency configuration file:

```
{
  "name": "final-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "4.8.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

What could be the problem? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: May be author is using older version of firebase and you are using latest version

Comment: @santoshsingh Ok and so how can I update my code to propperly perform the query?

Comment: new firebase api have some breaking changes rollback to older one

Comment: try this `npm install -g firebase-tools@^2.1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to Look at the Readme of Angular Fire repo

```
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
```

Check this [`link`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md).

Also For older versions of Angular Fire you can try this below `Rc 4.0.0.2`.

```
import {AngularFireDatabase} from "angularfire2/database/database";
constructor(private af: AngularFireDatabase) { }
```